# Why does one of the arguments in this MPU-6050 code mean something different from the official Arduino documentation?

Tags: arduino, i2c, mpu6050

So, I am currently attempting to read data from a MPU-6050 IMU chip. Since this is my first time with I2C and using hardware this advanced, I am following along with a code I found on [this website.](https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/arduino-and-mpu6050-accelerometer-and-gyroscope-tutorial/#comments) In this section of the code (which is found in the MPU6050 Arduino Code section of the website), it says that the '6' in the `Wire.requestFrom`  function reads 6 registers.

```
void loop() {
  // === Read acceleromter data === //
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);
  Wire.write(0x3B); // Start with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU, 6, true); // Read 6 registers total, each axis value is stored in 2 registers
  //For a range of +-2g, we need to divide the raw values by 16384, according to the datasheet
  AccX = (Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read()) / 16384.0; // X-axis value
  AccY = (Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read()) / 16384.0; // Y-axis value
  AccZ = (Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read()) / 16384.0; // Z-axis value
```

This is where I get confused. From the [Arduino documentation website](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/wire/requestfrom/), it states that the second argument, the `quantity` argument tells the number of bytes to return. So, I have two questions:

1. Given that the `Wire.write(0x3B)` line only says to write to one register (which only outputs 1 byte from my understanding of the MPU 6050 register datasheet), how does the `requestFrom` return more than 1?
2. Hypothetically, if the '6' indicates the number of registers to read, why isn't the documentation clearer about this? Or is the Arduino definition clear for programmers to understand?

Excuse any ignorance or lack of clarity in my question; From the start, I've been pretty overwhelmed with the whole I2C communication process. But, I'm trying to learn it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The device will output each register’s value when read and then advance to next register. So in burst mode all six registers are read. This makes sure the values are coherent and no update to any values happens in the middle. I can’t find a specific part of documentation that explains this mode of operation though, which is a bit weird.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense to me. Is this something that is known in the I2C process or FIFO or whatnot?

Comment: Okay, that makes sense to me. Is this something that is known in the I2C process or FIFO or whatnot?

Comment: To my knowledge it’s device dependent. Some devices have a flag stating if you want it to operate this way, some just do it. In this case it’s a choice made to make sure the recipient doesn’t read one byte from time X and next byte of the 16bit value from time Y, as might happen when reading single bytes